Problem in TensorFlow Installation in Anaconda Navigator: LibMambaUnsatisfiableError
I get the following error when trying to install TensorFlow using Anaconda Navigator:
LibMambaUnsatisfiableError: Encountered problems while solving:
  - nothing provides bleach 1.5.0 needed by tensorboard-1.7.0-py35he025d50_1

Could not solve for environment specs
The following packages are incompatible
├─ pin-1 is installable and it requires
│  └─ python 3.11.* , which can be installed;
└─ tensorflow is not installable because there are no viable options
   ├─ tensorflow [1.10.0|1.9.0] would require
   │  └─ python 3.5.* , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   ├─ tensorflow [1.10.0|1.11.0|...|2.1.0] would require
   │  └─ python 3.6.* , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   ├─ tensorflow [1.13.1|1.14.0|...|2.9.1] would require
   │  └─ python 3.7.* , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   ├─ tensorflow [1.7.0|1.7.1|1.8.0] would require
   │  └─ tensorboard [>=1.7.0,<1.8.0 |>=1.8.0,<1.9.0 ], which requires
   │     └─ bleach 1.5.0 , which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
   ├─ tensorflow [2.10.0|2.8.2|2.9.1] would require
   │  └─ python 3.10.* , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   ├─ tensorflow [2.10.0|2.3.0|...|2.9.1] would require
   │  └─ python 3.8.* , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   └─ tensorflow [2.10.0|2.5.0|2.6.0|2.8.2|2.9.1] would require
      └─ python 3.9.* , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported.

Pins seem to be involved in the conflict. Currently pinned specs:
 - python 3.11.* (labeled as 'pin-1')


How can I solve this problem? Do you have any help or suggestions?
Thanks.
You can also see the screenshot.
Screenshot 1

the problem is mainly your python version so
in your bash
deactivate your environment with :
conda deactivate
then create a new environment  :
conda create -n env python=3.8
activate it :
conda activate env
now install tensorflow :
conda install tensorflow

Hi! Your answer could be improved by reformatting it in a more readable way. Here is a help article about formatting on StackOverflow.

I had the same problem, try
pip install tensorflow
it worked to me
